# Recommendation for a binary dataset for Computational Biology open access (as in a dataset with 1 and 0 that can be used to apply ML techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, public-dataset

I have a couple of modified ML methods that I want to test with biological binary data - specifically binary gene expression data - e.g. https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/69359/1/Thesis.pdf that might include a variable that could be used to be the target variable in ML classification. What I mean by binary data is the features are all either 0 or 1, so I expect a large dataset e.g this thesis. I am looking for any suggestions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it a bit more specific What kind of "biological data" do you need? How large a dataset? What do you mean by "binary"? Are you referring to the format of the data or do you want something that can only have two states?

Answer (score 2):

Kaggle has a cats v dogs dataset if you want to try your hand at biological image classification: https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats

The DREAM challenge competitions are usually specifically oriented to solving biological classification or learning problems with ML: http://dreamchallenges.org/